# Getting a specific value in a Datagrid in MSDN visual basic

Tags: vb.net, msdn, cells

So I have a simple question, but after so many Google searches I cant seem to find a good example.

I'm trying to get a very specific cell from a datagrid. I Know the datagrid is working, as it runs fine and I can see all of the values I want to see from it in my program. What I want to do is get a  value from a specific cell the datagrid. I was hoping it would be something simple like this.

dataGrid1.DataSource = someDataSet

dataGrid.DataBind()

Label1.Text = dataGrid1.CellValue(rowValue, columnValue).ToString() 'this isn't valid

What I keep seeing is something with e.userclickshere or something else, which will be useful later on, but right now I just want to get a specific cell from a dg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW: One way is to get it directly from your someDataSet.  This way you won't mix data and UI.

Regarding how to get data out of the dataset - play with intellisense.
It is something like

```
Dim myValue as Object = myDataset.Tables(myTableIndexOftenZero).Rows(myRowIndex)(myFieldIndex)
```

But don't use untyped datasets unless you have to. Typed datasets gives you names and types for free.
It is something like

```
Dim myValue as Integer = myDataset.MyTable(myRowIndex).MyProperty
```

BTW: IIRC you can feed your grid with a table like

```
myTable.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
```

BTW2: If you inherit from Dataset and implement your own stuff you can get to some nice protected events and properties to react to changes in the dataset/datatable. But I would today instead go for BTW3 as below.

BTW3: Today you might want to get rid of datasets at all and instead use lists of classes. Earlier there was some friction around this but today...

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that afterwards too.
My dataset is set up simply by 
Dim someDataSet As DataSet = GetTablefromSqlServer()
how could I get it from someDataSet?

Label1.Text = someDataSet.cell(rowValue, columnvalue)
?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
Dim dt as datatable = someDataSet.Tables(0) 'Or whatever table is

Label1.text = dt(rowValue)(columnValue).toString()
```